# How to Open new Activity while selecting item from spinner? Trying to Open WebView after clicking item on spinner

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Wanted to Open New Activity after selecting item from spinner
I'm creating App for college project but stuck here
here is the code

here is the spinner in layout

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    >
</Spinner>
```

here are the items in the strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Spinner</string>
<string name="select_bikes">Bike Reviews</string>
<string-array name="bike_names">

    <item>Ducati Panigale</item>
    <item>Suzuki Hayabusa</item>
    </string-array>
```

here is the code that I want to make it able to open another activity when I click on the items

```
 Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
    adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.bike_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)+" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use **[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)** to start Activity

> An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an **Activity**.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)+" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(i==0){
                Intent  intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URl","https://stackoverflow.com/");
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(i==1){
                Intent  intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URl","https://stackoverflow.com/");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)+" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         startActivity(new Intent(ActivityName.this,RecieverActivity.class));

    }
```

Comment: I have 5 to 6 items so is this code enough? for each item? i have to open different webpages for different items present in spinner

Comment: adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) will give you the selected item position use an if/switch statement to check condtions for  which page is to be loaded

Comment: can u please provide me the code? of  two switch cases pls?